# Не хочет работать nginx + gunicorn на Centos7

Tags: linux, django, nginx, centos7, gunicorn

Имеется ОС на базе Centos7

в кач-ве сервера используется Nginx

.conf файл

```
server {
listen      81;
listen      488 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/caravanofmoney.cash/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/caravanofmoney.cash/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
server_name myip mydomain;

location /static/ {
    root /home/karavan/caravanmoney;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/karavan/caravanmoney;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host:81;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney/caravanmoney.socket;
}
```

При вводе адреса (прим. mysite.xxx:81 ) получаю 502 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот демон:

```
[Unit]
Description=karavan server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=karavan
Group=karavan
WorkingDirectory=/home/karavan/caravanmoney/
ExecStart=/home/karavan/env/bin/gunicorn --name karavan --workers 4 --max-requests 10 --user karavan --group karavan --log-level debug --error-logfile /home/karavan/caravanmoney/error.log --timeout 300 --bind unix:/home/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney/caravanmoney.socket caravanmoney.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Когда запускаю команду напрямую из консоли:

```
/home/karavan/env/bin/gunicorn --name karavan --workers 4 --max-requests 10 --user karavan --group karavan --log-level debug --error-logfile /home/karavan/caravanmoney/error.log --timeout 300 --bind unix:/home/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney/caravanmoney.socket caravanmoney.wsgi:application
```

Она крутится, но без каких-либо оповещений. В подобных ситуациях с ее помощью узнавал в чем ошибка и дебажил, но на Centos это не хочет работать

Вот директории и их содержимое

```
>>> pwd && ls 
/home/karavan/caravanmoney
bot  caravanmoney  error.log  main.html  manage.py  payments  PaymentSystems  pm.py  sample.log  static  statistic
```

Что показывает `error.log`

```
 logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: karavan
  default_proc_name: caravanmoney.wsgi:application
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7faf84f812f0>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7faf84f81400>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7faf84f81510>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7faf84f81620>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7faf84f81730>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7faf84f81840>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7faf84f81950>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7faf84f81a60>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7faf84f81b70>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7faf84f81c80>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7faf84f81d08>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7faf84f81e18>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7faf84f81f28>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7faf84cfd0d0>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7faf84cfd1e0>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29006] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29006] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29006] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney/caravanmoney.socket (29006)
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29006] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29009] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29009
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29011] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29011
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29013] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29013
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29014] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29014
[2018-07-04 07:37:30 +0300] [29006] [DEBUG] 4 workers
[2018-07-04 07:37:35 +0300] [29006] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2018-07-04 07:37:36 +0300] [29006] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

***UPD***

Включил SElinux, далее использовал

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/karavan/caravanmoney
```

К сожалению, не помогло :(

Дальше решил перенести проект в `/var/www/html/`. Создал там директорию `karavan` с виртуальным окружением и самим проектом 
В целом путь вышел таким `/var/www/html/karavan/caravanmoney`, при запуске gunicorn все также молчит

Вот обновленная команда запуска:

```
/var/www/html/karavan/env/bin/gunicorn --name root --workers 4 --max-requests 10 --user root --group root --log-level debug --error-logfile /var/www/html/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney/error.log --timeout 300 --bind unix:/var/www/html/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney/caravanmoney.socket caravanmoney.wsgi:application
```

И nginx

```
location /static/ {
    root /var/www/html/karavan/caravanmoney;
}

location /media/ {
    root /var/www/html/karavan/caravanmoney;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host:81;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/karavan/caravanmoney/caravanmoney.socket;
}
```

}

При переходе в браузере выбивает `This site can’t be reached. Refused to connect.`

Answer (score 1):

У вас путь /home/karavan
Даже когда selinux выключен, система будет биться но не допустит отдачи контента во вне.
Самое простое перенесите (если есть возможность) в директорию по умолчанию для веб сервера - типа /var/www/html.

Или

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/karavan/caravanmoney
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я обновил свою тему, с результатами исполнения ваших советов, не могли бы вы подсказать что на этот раз не так?

Comment: Хорошо, можно запустить вашу связку без SSL сертификата, просто по http 80 порт? Какой у вас пользователь, root (стоит добавить тогда пользователя nginx в его группу: usermod -a -G root nginx)? 
У вас VDS? Selinux лучше пока отключить.